# Azure Data Factory Data Flow - Parquet, Schema and Data Type "Any"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I have a Data Flow in Azure Data Factory who is reading data from a Parquet file. It works smooth for all the files except one.
The Data Flow is failing with the error: `Could not read or convert schema fro the file ...`
After going into debug mode, I realise that one of my column was treated by the data flow as data type `any`(see screenshot below). In the original file the schema read the type `TIME_MILLIS` for this column. How can I tell Data Flow to treat this column as `Text` at least?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is being inferred from the Import projection method automatically, you can try **manually importing the schema from a file** in the source dataset properties.

If that doesn't help, you can **cast** that specific column into required data type using  **Derived Column** step with [**conversion functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conversion-functions#conversion-function-list).